# How to programmatically look up email server information

Tags: php, email

If a user supplies an email, let's say something like hello.world@example.com, is there a public database where I can programmatically lookup the connection information for their Mail server (my service would let the user supply an email which then would allow my software to send automated emails from it.)

How can I find out if their server is pop3, Imap or smtp programatically. What about the port and security protocol  (tls or ssl)?

How can I find out if the mail server is a different domain then the email's suffix. (I.e. the user is using shared hosting.)

Are there only paid options for this service?

Note: it is preferred that the solution be in PHP, or even better, a http REST service.

Comment: You cannot. A properly configured server does not reveal nothing of those.

Comment: Windows mail app is able to do this though (smart detection) How does it do it?

Comment: In order to send emails as the user, through their mail server, you'd need not only their email address but their password. You'd have to have quite the compelling application to convince people to hand over their passwords to you.

Comment: @MichaelSohnen presumably it tries multiple different generic options it's aware about. But you cannot infer it just from a hostname or simply by connecting to it.

Comment: I see that now. The reason why I am asking this is because people would like to send their administrative emails from a noreply@ account. But they may want to use their own and not one I can provide because I do not own the domain they want.

Comment: You can use a standard DNS lookup to get the MX records for their domain, and then make some educated guesses at the port the server uses for SMTP (25, 465, 587 and 2525 are common). But without the password, that information does you no good.

Comment: If these people want to use their own email addresses so that responses come back to them, look into the Reply-To header.

Comment: I would ask the user for the password, my service would have to be as trustworthy as something like thunderbird or windoes Mail app

Comment: +thanks Greg Schmidt for the answer

Comment: This is how a mail client would do it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Thunderbird/Autoconfiguration

Comment: An API... https://autoconfig.thunderbird.net/v1.1/gmail.com

Comment: So, you can totally spoof the sending email address. This is extremely common. Basically, most email servers, unless they implement SPF or the like, don't care what you specify in the `mail from` command, i.e., I can say I am `president@whitehouse.gov` and most email servers will accept it...

Comment: @varlogtim For various values of "accept it". These days, they'll typically look up the SPF record, see you're not on the list, and send it straight to spam.

Comment: You are correct. Working in email security for many years I found that most servers do not implement SPF, DMARC, and DKIM... However, I think I am somewhat lost on what the OP is actually trying to do... Is he trying to send an email as someone else, or to someone else?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do this. At least for SMTP. And... you can send an email as a specific user easily....

### Explanation of how a client sends an email

When an email client goes to send an email to does the following steps:

1. It extracts the domain portion portion of the email, e.g., "gmail.com" given "bob@gmail.com"
2. It checks to see if there is a DNS record published called an Mail Exchange or MX record. An MX record contains the following information:

   - Time To Live, i.e., how long the record is valid for
   - Weight, i.e., what order the client should attempt connections. Lowest to highest
   - The server A record, or IP address.

You can use the `dig` or `nslookup` command to query for MX records published for a domain.

Examples:

```
root@dib:~# nslookup -querytype=mx gmail.com
Server:         172.31.0.2
Address:        172.31.0.2#53

Non-authoritative answer:
gmail.com       mail exchanger = 10 alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com       mail exchanger = 20 alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com       mail exchanger = 30 alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com       mail exchanger = 40 alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com       mail exchanger = 5 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.

Authoritative answers can be found from:

root@dib:~# dig +short MX gmail.com
40 alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
5 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
10 alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
20 alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
30 alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
```

3. If there is an MX record, the client attempts to make a port 25 connection to the server listed. In this example we are going to use `gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com`. A quick test is to check to see if a banner is displayed when you connect.

Example using `telnet`:

```
root@dib:~# telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
Trying 74.125.197.27...
Connected to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.google.com ESMTP m8-v6si7680016plt.29 - gsmtp
quit
221 2.0.0 closing connection m8-v6si7680016plt.29 - gsmtp
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

The banner is the `220 mx.google.com ESMTP b8-v6si8705269pls.261 - gsmtp` part.

4. Most email clients use opportunistic TLS, i.e., if the server offers TLS it will use it, if not it doesn't. To determine if the server is offering TLS we need to issue an EHLO command. This is the extended SMTP Hello. What we are looking for is a `STARTTLS` command being offered.

Example:

```
root@dib:~# telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
Trying 74.125.197.27...
Connected to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.google.com ESMTP s83-v6si8350062pfg.175 - gsmtp
ehlo stackoverflow.com
250-mx.google.com at your service, [123.123.123.123]
250-SIZE 157286400
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
quit
221 2.0.0 closing connection s83-v6si8350062pfg.175 - gsmtp
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

We can see that the SMTP servers for the domain `gmail.com` are indeed offering TLS.

5. I am not going to explain the rest of the SMTP conversation but you can Google it... :)

### Solution for answering these things with PHP

1. "is there a public database where I can programmatically lookup the connection information for their Mail server"

   - Yes, the database is the `Domain Name System`. There are many ways to do it; however, PHP has a nifty builtin function for this. It is `getmxrr()`.

Example:

```
root@dib:~# cat mxrecord.php
<?php
$email_addr = "bob@gmail.com";
list($local, $domain) = explode('@', $email_addr);

getmxrr($domain, $mxrecords); // http://php.net/manual/en/function.getmxrr.php

var_dump($mxrecords);
?>
root@dib:~# php mxrecord.php
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(26) "gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com"
  [1]=>
  string(31) "alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com"
  [2]=>
  string(31) "alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com"
  [3]=>
  string(31) "alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com"
  [4]=>
  string(31) "alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com"
}
```

You can loop through the results and answer you question "How can I find out if the mail server is a different domain then the email's suffix".

2. "What about the port and security protocol?" The port is always 25. That is why we have protocol definitions. The security protocol is a little trickier...

Basically, if you want to know things like; protocol, cipher, Certificate Authority, etc... you need to use the OpenSSL library... or just parse the open for `openssl s_client` ... This would make this a really long answer if I covered the TLS bit here too... but ... run this in a shell and check out the output:

`openssl s_client -connect gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com:25 -starttls smtp`

This basically just handles the TLS handshake with the server and spits out all the information you want. PHP has OpenSSL libs so you can likely use those from within PHP ...

### Sending an email as another user

Basically, unless an email server implements SPF of something of the like, you can "spoof" the sender, i.e., put whatever you want in the `mail from` command. This is an extremely common practice, however, some email servers will block spoofs. There are things you can do to make your emails more likely to be received.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible programatically. I am not aware of any well-maintained APIs that provide this service but you could generate your own using by pre-populating a database table with the major email provider (gmail, hotmail etc.) settings. There is a list e.g. here: https://domar.com/smtp_pop3_server

If your user has a different provider you could try some educated guesses, e.g. `smtp.domain.com`, `mail.domain.com` or you could use the PHP function [getmxrr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getmxrr.php) and try connecting to the MX server, as some smaller providers will use the same server for MX and SMTP (this is not a guarantee though, hence trying the others first).

When I say "try" I mean using [PHP sockets](http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php) to connect to e.g. port 25 (for SMTP) on the domain under examination and checking if you get a valid response.

Your final fallback would be asking users to provide the details themselves.

Answer (score -1):

false, those answers are for incoming smtp server, for outcoming smtp server you need to check on mail provider settings *may be is your same hosting provider or a 3th party mail provider

Comment: For the outgoing mail server, most modern providers post an "SPF" record, which is a special type of TXT record which specifies the servers allowed to send mail as that particular domain. While it isn't guaranteed, most  domains will have these records created.